# Creating dynamic url doesn't work when using other variable than id

Tags: php, url, dynamic, mysqli, get

I'm creating dynamic webpages for my website.

I got an archive.php file where I use the following code:

**Code archive.php:**

```
<?php
(connect to database)
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table-example` WHERE id = $id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['text'];
}// end while
}// end if
else { echo '0 results';}
?>
```

**Link to the dynamic page:**

```
<a href="/archive?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
```

**Example of variable "id" in database:**

123

**Result:**

When I access this page, it opens up http://example.com/archive?id=123 with the correct data.

So far, so good. But the problem is that I want to create a url with another variable from my database. So I changed my code into this:

**Code archive.php:**

```
<?php
(connect to database)
$url = $_GET['url'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table-example` WHERE url = $url";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['text'];
}// end while
}// end if
else { echo '0 results';}
?>
```

**Link to the dynamic page:**

```
<a href="/archive?url=<?php echo $row['url'];?>">
```

**Example of variable "url" in database:**

this-is-a-new-article

**Result:**

0 results.

**Important note:** I KNOW that I'm open to MYSQLi injection! I'm going to change my code after I fixed this problem.

Comment: ... `WHERE url = '$url'"; Are you missing quotes, aren't?

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks for the quick reply! Any idea why it worked for the variable id without the quotes?

Comment: Because IDs are integer numbers, you don't need to quote them. But varchar/text values are like strings, you must quote them to identify that you're sending text, and not variables or functions.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. Php and mysql is still new to me...

Comment: You're welcome :) but switch this code to prepared statements. You wouldn't have this problem since you'd define strictly which type of data is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes because it is a string

WHERE url = '$url'